# Proxy script on c++ for linux

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, proxy, g++

I have a code, that enables proxy on Linux. It should work like this: I'm starting the program, writing the `IP:port` in ("stop" to disable proxy), the program writes into terminal `export http_proxy://(entered proxy)`, if I have entered "stop", it writes `unset http_proxy`. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char proxy[20];
char choice;
cout << "Enter ip:port ('stop' to disable): ";
cin >> proxy;
if(proxy != "stop"){
cout << "Do you want to use it as ftp(y/n): "
cin >> chioce;
}

if(proxy == "stop"){
system("unset http_proxy");
system("unset ftp_proxy");
}
else if(choice == 'y'){
system("export http_proxy=http:/"+'/'+proxy+'/');
system("export ftp_proxy=http:/"+'/'+proxy+'/');
}
else{
system("export http_proxy=http:/"+'/'+proxy+'/');
}

}
```

But when I compile with g++, I get this error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘char [20]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

This is my first time with `""+a+""`. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Even if you fix the compilation error, your program will not do anything useful except to print messages on the screen. None of the executed commands will have any effect, whatsoever. Environment variables don't work this way. You will discover that despite no matter what you do, your shell's variables will remain unset.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to the fact that you cannot use `+` to concatenate string literals. Your best bet is to use `std::string` to build your strings.

```
system(("export http_proxy=http:/"s + '/' + proxy + '/').c_str());
```

`proxy` should also be a `std::string`.  That way you don't have to worry about what size to make it or buffer overflows.

Also, as Sam Varshavchik pointed out, this won't do what you want anyway.  `system()` creates a child process with its own environment; that goes away once the call is done.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael! The programm compiles, but as you and @Sam Varshavchik said, system() doesnt change anything. So u know, i began with linux 2 days ago XD. Is there any solution, to get this app to work fine?

Comment: There is no portable way to do this that I'm aware of.  A common but implementation dependent way to do this is to use a third possible signature to main. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function.  I've never used this myself and I'm not sure if you can write to the environment safely this way, but it may be worth exploring.

Comment: OK, i think im not so far, to do such things. Thank you!

Comment: You missed the `using std::literals::string_literals;` needed for this.

Comment: @Hazker - no, a process can not normally modify the environment of another running process (some exceptions exist, via `ptrace()` and the like, intended for debugging).  This is a Good Thing - if environment variables could change unexpected at runtime, then it would be much harder to reason about program execution!